# Flutter restore SQLite Db from Dropbox

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm trying to implement a restore db for my app, to cover the case of phone renewals.

I've just uploaded my db file "database.db" to Dropbox and I manage to download the file back again, but whenever I try to open the Db after downloading I get an exception and seems to be that the file is returned somehow corrupted. Do I have to save it to dropbox or download with some specific parameters?

```
E/SQLiteLog(16429): (26) file is not a database
D/SQLiteConnection(16429): Corruption detected - isPrimary: true, address: @2e80143
E/SQLiteDatabase(16429): Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.testdropbox.test/app_flutter/database.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase(16429): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is not a database (code 26 SQLITE_NOTADB[26]): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

```
Future downloadTest() async {
    if (await checkAuthorized(authorize: true)) {
      Directory docsDirectory =
          await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String dbPath = join(docsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);

      await _dbService.closeDb();

      final result =
          await Dropbox.download('/db/$DB_NAME', dbPath, (downloaded, total) {
        print('progress $downloaded / $total');
      });

      print(result);
      print(io.File(dbPath).statSync());
      await _dbService.openDb();
    }
  }

Future uploadTest() async {
    if (await checkAuthorized(authorize: true)) {
      io.Directory docsDirectory =
          await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String filepath = join(docsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);

      io.File(filepath).writeAsStringSync(
          'contents.. from ' + (io.Platform.isIOS ? 'iOS' : 'Android') + '\n');

      final result =
          await Dropbox.upload(filepath, '/db/$DB_NAME', (uploaded, total) {
        print('progress $uploaded / $total');
      });
      print(result);

      var _content = await listFolder('');
      print(_content);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my apollogies on this, I messed up the variable with the path, and was writting text and overwritting the database file prior to dropbol upload in this line:

```
io.File(filepath).writeAsStringSync(
          'contents.. from ' + (io.Platform.isIOS ? 'iOS' : 'Android') + '\n');
```